# Vim Highlight Perl code inside html

Tags: vim

I want code in [perl] highlighted as perl.

Here's my code:

```
so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/html.vim

syn include @perlTop $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/perl.vim
syn region myperl matchgroup=Function start="\[perl " end="\]" contains=@perlTop
syn match myComment "\[--.*--\]"
```

1.The Perl code not been highlighted.

2.The comment not worked in <style> or <script> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine; the problem is that existing syntax regions obscure the matches of your additional regions. For example, the part in between `<style>` tags is matched by a `cssStyle` syntax group. To embed your Perl regions in there, you have to append `containedin=cssStyle` to the `:syn region myperl` definition.

Comment: Thx alot.I add containedin=cssstyle, javascript at the eol. Tags itself are highlight in <style> & <script> now. But the perl codes  inside [perl ..... ] still not work.Any ideal?

Comment: Do you know SyntaxAttr.vim? It's helpful to troubleshoot those issues. Unfortunately, `html.vim` is already quite complex, so adding another syntax is difficult indeed.